# Replace empty values in SQL query with symbol

Tags: sql, powershell

I need to rebuild my query:

```
foreach ($myDbin $dbsArr) {
 $SqlCmd.CommandText = "use [$myDb]
        Select LAST_NAME from test.[USER]
        Where ID = (Select Test_User_ID from test.UPGRADE
        Where KEYED_NAME Like '%$db%'
        and STATE = 'Active')"
}
 while ($objReader.read()) {

        foreach ($dbValue in $objReader.GetValue(0)) {
            $dbsArr +=  @($dbValue )
    
        }
   
    }
```

So this query is actually shows me some info, BUT, some columns might be empty so my further array to which I put these values breaks through.

How can I add some logic to this query like:

```
If (LAST_NAME is empty) {
LAST_NAME = '-'
}
```

But it's all should be done in SQL query, so for now I get like:

```
John 
Bob

Sam
```

in this case, my 3d and 5th values are empty(not null)
and I need to change these empty values by '-' such symbol for example.

So the result query will give me smth like:

```
John 
Bob
-
Sam
-
```

Comment: What you are looking is `coalesce()` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Dollar sign variables do not get replaced inside single quotes.  So change from '%$db%' to '%" + $db + "%'   The plus sign will combine strings. I put a double quotes to terminate the first part of the string then added the variable $db and then started a second string.